# How do I package all dependencies libraries of my c++ project in linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm first time using Linux and I have to use QT to make some c++ programs.

In windows, the easiest way to package the dependency libraries is to put all *.dll file with my *.exe into a folder and throw it to somebody.

What's the counterpart in linux to do the similar things. I didn't find any *.exe and *.dll in linux.

Comment: linux has the similar .exe (typically no extension) and .dll (typically .so extention) files

Comment: Here is a complete example of Qt program with Linux, Windows installation: https://github.com/xxxcucus/planes . However I am using cmake which I recommend to you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the canonical reference to this problem is this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html

With Linux you're best off sticking to the shared library approach, which you can either package yourself in a `.tar` for distribution, and you can find the dependencies by using `readelf -d` and then `find / | grep '<dep-name>'`. The other option is to distribute your binary as an `rpm/deb/other` which lists the dependencies it needs to run and will install them through the package manager.